# YouTube videos not working when the cookies are not accepted | cookieYes plugin

Tags: wordpress, cookies, youtube, integration, elementor

We just added the plugin CookieYes on our sites and we now see that all the YouTube videos are no longer working if the user is not accepting the cookies, which is normal. Is there a way to bypass this issue?

We use WordPress with Elementor to integrate our content/videos

Thank you all!

We tried already to add the links "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed" but with no luck